# how to link 3 different buttons with 3 different activities?

Tags: button, android-intent, android-activity, oncreate

I have 3 buttons on my menu screen and I want to link them 3 different activities. Every single button would extends different activity. How it is possible to do? I have no problem when I have 1 class and activity, but it makes problem when I have 3. Thank you.

Comment: How about posting either (a) something that works you want to extend or (b) something that nearly works for help? This would make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have three activities called `MainActivity`, `SettingsActivity` and `ProfileActivity`, you can do:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
Intent intent;
    Class<?> cls;
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.main:
        cls = MainActivity.class;
        break;
    case R.id.settings:
        cls = ScheduleView.class;
        break;
    case R.id.profile:
        cls = UserPrefsActivity.class;
        break;
    default:
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),"Should not happen");
        return false;
    }
    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), cls);
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
```